# JavaScript: Link URLs but remove 'http://' from displayed link text

Tags: javascript, regex

In a JavaScript regex, how would one turn e.g.

```
Check out http://example.com/foobar#123
```

into

```
Check out <a href="http://example.com/foobar#123">example.com/foobar#123</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why, or how, are these links being generated to include the `http://` protocol if you don't want it there? This is pretty simple, but should it deal with *all* potential protocols (`https://`, `ftp://`, `tel://`...)?

Comment: We have an internal news system where we put the same plain-text which we also paste into Facebook and Twitter, so for simplicity sake we're using the exact same text, and now when the news is displayed on our app, we want to format it like e.g. Twitter formats it (they also linkify it, but then get rid of the 'http://' for the display). https would be a plus, other protocols are realistically never needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this replace call:

```
s = 'Check out http://example.com/foobar#123';
repl = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/(\S+))/i, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
//=> Check out <a href='http://example.com/foobar#123'>example.com/foobar#123</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `str` is the string containing that text, it's a simple use of [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses):

```
str = str.replace(/(http:\/\/)([^ ]+)/g, '<a href="$1$2">$2</a>');
```

That assumes that there aren't *already* any link tags in the text, of course, because it will mess them up if there are. Doing this only *outside* of tags in the markup text is non-trivial (and can't be done absolutely reliably just with a single regular expression, you have to parse).

Comment: (Thanks! Both answers came in at the same time so I didn't know which one to mark as correct. Both are correct.)